# Is there a way to view setInterval behaviour in the browser as you can for event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, setinterval

Ive been learning to use the useEffect hook with events such as onClick and I can see that the event listeners are created in the chrome console and I can see that they can keep being created unless you clean them up.

I just came across an example using a setInterval in the useEffect hook which creates a new setInterval everytime the page loads - the example in the video states you should use a clearInterval in the useEffect to clean up the setInterval which makes sense to me.

However I can't see anywhere in the dev tools that the old setInterval was set and is still hanging around. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [plugin for Chrome DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/setinterval-sniffer/odkgihncjgklajjabihpoipfnpcjhdno)

Comment: thanks I had spotted this in a search but I wanted to check if there was a way that's built into the browser tools.